# Mirror flip video taken from front camera in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have a camera application which is able to capture images and record videos. However, when capturing images or recording videos from the device front facing camera the result is flipped, like you are looking at the mirror. I want to flip it again so it will look normal. I managed to do this with images by flipping the `Bitmap` using `Matrix` :

```
   public Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        float[] mirrorY = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
        matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);
        matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);
    }
```

I can't figure out how to flip videos taken by `MediaRecorder`, I know I can run a `ffmpeg` command:

```
-i /pathtooriginalfile/originalfile.mp4 -vf hflip -c:a copy /pathtosave/flippedfile.mp4
```

but I don't know how to run a `ffmpeg` command from code and I can't find a different way. There are a lot of topics discussing this issue but I couldn't find a solution to work. Notice: It is possible,  Snapchat got this to work somehow.

Thanks.

P.S Sorry for my English

Comment: Hi, did you figure out any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @dangling_refrenz Nope, never tried to solve this after this thread and the answers I got here, good luck anyway.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 i am facing same issue. did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Capturing images or recording video using front camera will always gives flipped images, which is expected as front camera works like you are looking at the mirror.

After getting the picture from the camera, flip the image back by  drawing the image into a new context.

Please try below code snippets. Refer [Android- Taking a picture from front facing camera rotates the photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853334/android-taking-a-picture-from-front-facing-camera-rotates-the-photo)

```
Matrix rotateRight = new Matrix();
rotateRight.preRotate(90);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13 && CameraActivity.frontCamera) {
    float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    rotateRight = new Matrix();
    Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
    matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

    rotateRight.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

    rotateRight.preRotate(270);

}

final Bitmap rImg= Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0,
                img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);
```

Comment: You can not flip video in one shot, for that you have to override onPreviewFrame() callback and then need to flip each and every frame before writing into the buffer.

Comment: Okay, Thanks.. It will take too long I think.